# Where is this Python3 module layout and import method defined?

Tags: python, python-3.x, module

With the following module layout:

```
/path/in/pythonpath/
  mymodule/
    __init__.py
    _mymodule-cpython-37m-darwin.so
```

In Python 2.7, __init__.py could import the .so as follows:

```
import _mymodule
```

But in Python 3.7, I found that _mymodule was not found unless I added the mymodule directory to the PYTHONPATH:

```
PYTHONPATH=/path/in/pythonpath:/path/in/pythonpath/mymodule
```

I found this approach used in the typed_ast module installed on the system:

```
...site-packages/typed_ast/
  __init__.py
  ast3.py
  _ast3.cpython-37m-darwin.so
```

Where ast3.py imported _ast3 as follows:

```
from typed_ast import _ast3
from typed_ast._ast3 import *
```

Following this model with mymodule also works without having to modify the PYTHONPATH:

```
from mymodule import _mymodule
from mymodule._mymodule import *
```

My question is around what changed and what is the right thing to do for "mymodule" - and where is this defined? I didn't find this explicitly covered in the PEPs or the Python Documentation. I suspect it is implicit in some of the module docs and I missed it.

Answer (score 0):

The original problem statement was incorrect.

In Python 2.7, the module I was working with had a Python27 directory with _mymodule.so in it:

```
Python27/
    _mymodule.so
```

And it explicitly added the Python27 to the path. So it is no surprise that Python 3 couldn't find the module as the subdirectory was eliminated and the versioning naming scheme was applied to the .so file.

As to the two import statements. Both are not required, unless you want to be able to access _mymodule functions directly as well as prefixed by _mymodule. This is typically done for legacy reasons.

The answer to my question is: you asked the wrong question because you mischaracterized the problem and, what you want is:

```
from mymodule._mymodule import *
```